# Bootstrap: hide the line between the rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to divide a page in 2 rows with bootstrap and when I do that, there comes up a line in between. Can I remove/hide it somehow?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 panel">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px">Button1</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 panel">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button2</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You must have some other elements or some css as Bootstrap doesn't add any line between rows or cols. Check this pen http://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/XjgEBm

Comment: Is it inside another element as your code should just show palin empty space if not inside something else!100%

Comment: @BeNice, I edited my code. As you can see I have everything in a container + rows.

Comment: Don't think this should be down voted. C.R. did a pretty clear question asking about a common new Bootstrap user problem. The "col not wrapped properly in a row" is a common problem for Bootstrap newbs (I know it took ME ages to work this out) . Think this might turn out to be a useful post actually.

Answer (score 1):

The `.panel` adds a box-shadow. Either don't use it or remove it with..

```
.panel {
    box-shadow: initial;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/fNXo7yZu2T

Comment: Hey, that helped thanks, but now I have a problem that my elements are nested on each other without any free space in between :/

Comment: So then use the panel inside the col, and remove the shadow as suggested. That answers your question.

Comment: Also, you should always place `col-*` inside `row` for proper padding and alignment. So for example you should have another `row` around your inner `col-md-2`.

Comment: You have the nesting because you have the rows and cols all mixed up - see above

Comment: @BeNice What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should place your 2 main .col-md divs inside one common .row, not two different rows.

[see bootstrap guide](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

And then play with your .col-md divs.

I suggest the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px">Button1</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 panel">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button2</button>
                        </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Columns need to be wrapped in rows and that is ALL the columns at the same level - you have created 2 rows with just single columns inside.

IE you have created 2 panels - panels need to differentiate between each other - therefore the line! (If you want to use panels properly check out http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels and/or http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_panels.asp.)

You should be **living** at [getboostrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/) until u get happy with BS!

Basic BS layout is

```
row
 col col col
row 
  col
  row - a row of columns inside another row (this sorts out the padding etc).
    col 
    col
row
  col
  col
etc.
```

All wrapped in a `container` (containers should NOT be nested but they can be stacked one after the other).

Hope that makes sense (think it is clearer than HTML)

Columns always (well almost always - there are a couple of weird exceptions) need to be wrapped in rows otherwise padding, margins etc. go all over the place (took me ages to work out this simple rule).

It takes a while to get BS into your system.

One tip if you are using an IDE: Set up an insert (live template in PHPStorm) to do -

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
</div>
<!-- end col next to row -->
```

I do this 100 times a day now! Saves sooooo much time.